# Implementing Resnet as a NetGraph?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Does anyone know of a Mathematica v11.1 implementation for any of the Resnets, e.g. a NetModel or WLNet for [Resnet-1000](https://github.com/KaimingHe/resnet-1k-layers)?

Loading the MXNet weights from the model zoo for both resnet or resnext doesn't work since layer type **elemwise_add** is not supported:

[image]

Comment: There is pretrain MXNet weight available for Resnet in the [MXNet model zoo](http://data.dmlc.ml/mxnet/models/imagenet/resnet/). Maybe you can load them into Mathematica. By the way, I'm interested in what work do you do with Resnet? I'm guessing that it is very slow to evaluate.

Comment: The reason I ask for an implementation is because the import failed. @xslittlegrass

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've fixed the importer for the next update. In the meantime, here's the ResNet-18 model as a WLNet file. It has an image encoder and class decoder attached: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2dQMmlwPBAnQWZlXzFCT204MUU/view?usp=sharing.

Here's the corresponding import code:

```
syns = Import["~/Downloads/Nets/ResNet/synset.txt", "Lines"];

model = ImportMXNetModel[
   "~/Downloads/Nets/ResNet/resnet-18-symbol.json",
   "~/Downloads/Nets/ResNet/resnet-18-0000.params"
];

model = NetReplacePart[model, {
    {"bn_data", "MovingVariance"} -> model[["bn_data", "MovingVariance"]]/(256^2),
    {"bn_data", "MovingMean"} -> model[["bn_data", "MovingMean"]]/256,
    "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", 224}], 
    "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", syns}]
}];

Export["ResNet-18.wlnet", model]
```

Comment: Thanks! NiN doesn't import either for this same reason. I think it would be really great to add in a tutorial about interaction with lower-level stuff like this (I wouldn't have thought to alter this {"bn_data", "MovingVariance"} property of the net).